# Error while saving data downloaded from S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, fs

I am trying to save a file in a local directory from my s3 bucket. When I run the code everything seems to work fine because no errors are prompted in the console but when I open the directory the file size is just 15 bytes and it's the same story with on file I try to download.

I tried to download a text file and inside I found written `[object Object]`, can anyone help me? This is the function code:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.getObject(
{ Bucket: "chat-mp-files", Key: conf[1] },
   function (error, data) {
      if (error != null) {
         console.log(err)
      } else {
         fs.closeSync(fs.openSync(pathstr + '/r/' + conf[1], 'w'));
         fs.writeFile(pathstr + '/r/' + conf[1], data, function (err) {
            if (err) {
               console.log(err);
            } else {
               console.log("ok");
            }
         });
      });
```

Comment: what module are you using? maybe the module you use returns an stream which can be piped into `fs.createFileStream`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved my issue using the official docs section provided by Amazon [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html#Amazon_S3__Streaming_Objects_to_Files_on_Disk__getObject_)